Help identifying a source for medical/bioprocess rotational pinch valve
I am attempting to identify a type of pinch valve that I have seen used in a few different bioprocess and medical blood/fluid perfusion systems. The valve appears to be actuated by a stepper/servo motor and works by rotating a cylindrical piece to crush a piece of deformable tubing (similar to the action of a peristaltic pump, but only acting as a valve). See image below for an example.

Screenshot taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUfsvwYXig (starting @ 2:54)
I've been trying to find commercially available options for this type of valve, but the only one I've found is from DrM Life Science (https://drm-lifescience.com/single-use-valve/), but images of the product appear to be more at the 3d printed prototype stage.
Any insight into other options for this type of valve would be much appreciated.

have you tried googling "pinch valve"? My employer, who shall remain nameless, has several brands of pinch valve targeted at bioprocess industry, which anyone can quickly find near the top of the search results. Most big names that sell valves in industrial automation and process automation, have options, which will likewise come up. Most of them have cam action, the difference is that sometimes the cam is external, sometimes it is internal.

PS - your video link is broken

Just for completeness, noting that there would be additional limitations (e.g. gentler action) on valves and pumps, for handling whole blood, compared to general 'bioprocess' use. And substantially different regulatory compliance, to the point that it would be a unique manufacturing operation and possibly unique business unit selling system components into that market, if whole blood is handled for clinical medicine.
